# ¿Es posible usar input-lg e input-xs juntos?

Tags: html, bootstrap, css3, formularios, bootstrap-tags-input

Estoy usando bootstrap. Tengo un input con la clase: "input-lg". El problema es que en teléfonos quiero que este input sea más pequeño.
Yo puedo solucionar esto verificando la resolución desde javascript y quitandole esta clase en telefonos; tambien podría usar media queries para modificar el tamaño. Pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera más fácil, algo así como:

```
<input class="input-lg input-xs">
```

Answer (score 3):

Al estar utilizando Bootstrap como *framework* de trabajo puedes beneficiarte de sus estructuras para controlar tanto los tamaños como los espacios que ocupan tus *inputs* dándole el espacio que necesiten desde su contenedor mejor que aplicándoselo de manera directa.

Te dejo un ejemplo de buen uso de su estructura más básica en los diferentes *breakpoints* / *media queries* para un formulario.

```css
input {width:100%; padding:5px 15px;margin: 10px 0 !important}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<form class="form-group col-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Apellido">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes usar bootstrap grid:

```
col-lg-column y col-xs-column //siendo column el numero de 1 a 13

<input class="col-lg-10 col-xs-5">
```

Mira este link:

[bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/grid/)

Comment: La pantalla se divide en 12 columnas, no en 13.